# Jest encountered an unexpected token.This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

While running `npm test` I am getting error like:

> Jest encountered an unexpected token.
>
> This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest
> cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

This is my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "unite",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-sts": "3.272.0",
    "@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node": "3.272.0",
    "@aws-sdk/hash-node": "3.272.0",
    "@aws-sdk/signature-v4": "3.272.0",
    "@aws-sdk/types": "3.257.0",
    "@babel/core": "7.19.6",
    "@babel/node": "7.14.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.19.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.18.6",
    "@fontsource/open-sans": "^4.5.14",
    "@fontsource/pt-mono": "^4.5.11",
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "@jm18457/kafkajs-msk-iam-authentication-mechanism": "3.1.1",
    "@jpmuitk/app-header": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/avatar": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/banner": "^32.3.0",
    "@jpmuitk/button": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/button-bar": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/chart": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/column-layout": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/components": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/context-menu": "^32.3.0",
    "@jpmuitk/data-grid": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/dialog": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/drawer": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/dropdown": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/file-drop-zone": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/flag": "^32.3.0",
    "@jpmuitk/form-field": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/format": "^32.3.0",
    "@jpmuitk/icon": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/input": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/menu-button": "^32.3.0",
    "@jpmuitk/panel": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/spinner": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/theme": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/toast": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/toolbar": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/toolbar-next": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/tooltip": "32.2.2",
    "@jpmuitk/tree": "^32.3.0",
    "@jpmuitk/vertical-navigation": "^32.3.0",
    "@log4js-node/logstashudp": "^1.2.1",
    "@marketsui/blotter": "24.1.0",
    "@marketsui/blotter-grid": "24.1.0",
    "@marketsui/common": "24.1.0",
    "@marketsui/data-client": "24.1.0",
    "@marketsui/message-service": "24.1.0",
    "@marketsui/query-filter": "24.1.0",
    "@marketsui/query-manager": "24.1.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.58",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "3.3.10",
    "@salt-ds/ag-grid-theme": "^1.3.3",
    "@salt-ds/core": "^1.9.0",
    "@salt-ds/icons": "^1.7.0",
    "@salt-ds/theme": "^1.8.0",
    "@smithy/node-http-handler": "^2.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "13.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.35",
    "@uiservices/ui-platform-api-react-bindings": "2.17.74",
    "ag-grid-community": "28.2.1",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "28.2.1",
    "ag-grid-react": "28.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "aws4": "1.12.0",
    "axios": "0.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.1.4",
    "concurrently": "8.0.1",
    "config": "^3.3.7",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "6.4.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "env-cmd": "10.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "express": "4.18.1",
    "express-session": "1.17.3",
    "form-data": "4.0.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.2",
    "highcharts": "6.1.2",
    "ht": "0.0.2",
    "html-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "jest-junit": "^16.0.0",
    "jest-runner-eslint": "0.11.1",
    "jsonpointer": "4.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
    "kafkajs": "2.2.3",
    "local-storage": "2.0.0",
    "log4js": "^6.6.1",
    "moment": "2.29.4",
    "mongodb": "3.7.3",
    "node-localstorage": "2.2.1",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom-factories": "^1.0.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.21",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "request": "^2.79.0",
    "rsocket-core": "^0.0.27",
    "rsocket-flowable": "^0.0.27",
    "rsocket-websocket-client": "^0.0.27",
    "rsocket-websocket-server": "0.0.23",
    "socket.io": "4.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "4.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "sync-request": "^6.1.0",
    "timers-browserify": "^2.0.12",
    "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.9",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "uuid": "8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
    "webpack-merge": "5.8.0",
    "winston": "^3.8.1",
    "xml2js": "^0.6.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && react-app-rewired --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && react-app-rewired --max_old_space_size=8192 build",
    "test": "jest --coverage --testResultsProcessor='jest-junit'",
    "test:ci": "jest --config jest.ci.config.js",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "test:sonar": "jest --coverage --testResultsProcessor jest-sonar-reporter --runInBand --forceExit",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:feature": "npm run test:sonar",
    "test:PR": "npm run test:sonar",
    "test:develop": "npm run test:sonar",
    "test:release": "npm run test:sonar",
    "test:jules": "jest --coverage --testResultsProcessor jest-sonar-reporter",
    "start-dev-server": "env-cmd -f .env.dev npm run build && (npm run start-dev)",
    "start-uat-server": "env-cmd -f .env.uat npm run build && (npm run start-dev)",
    "start-prod-server": "env-cmd -f .env.prod npm run build && (npm run start-dev)",
    "start-dev": " concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm start\"",
    "server": "node src/server/server",
    "sonar": "sonar-scanner"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.15",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "ajv": "^7.2.4",
    "assert": "^2.1.0",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.21.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "console-browserify": "^1.2.0",
    "constants-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "domain-browser": "^4.23.0",
    "env-cmd": "10.1.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.7",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.26.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "jest": "26.6.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "26.6.0",
    "jest-localstorage-mock": "^2.4.22",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.0.0-11",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "punycode": "^2.3.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.11",
    "sass": "1.42.1",
    "sonarqube-scanner": "^3.0.1",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "tty-browserify": "^0.0.1",
    "url": "^0.11.3",
    "vm-browserify": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack-cli": "4.8.0"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "ie 11"
    ]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.x",
    "npm": "10.2.3"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "jestSonar": {
    "sonar56x": true,
    "reportPath": "sonar-reports",
    "indent": 4
  },
  "jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!d3-(array|format|geo))"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!build/**"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/src/stubs/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/src/stubs/styleMock.js",
      "^lodash-es$": "lodash"
    },
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "coverageReporters": [
      "lcov",
      "text"
    ]
  },
  "jest-junit": {
    "outputDirectory": "coverage/jest-junit-reports"
  }
}
```

I added many things `transformIgnorePatterns` to solve the issue I am getting but none of those working.